# Error compiling glib

Tags: debian, compiling, gcc, configure, glib

I am trying to compile glib 2.24.2 under Debian 64bit GNU/Linux 6.0.4 (squeeze) using:

```
gcc 4.0.3
glibc 2.3.6
```

Configure command:

```
 CPP="/home/swarkentin/externalBins/bin/cpp" \
 CC="/home/swarkentin/externalBins/bin/gcc" \
 CXX="/home/swarkentin/externalBins/bin/g++" \
 LDFLAGS="-L/home/swarkentin/externalBins/lib64 -L/home/swarkentin/externalBins/lib" \
 CFLAGS="-I /home/swarkentin/externalBins/include -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-omit-frame-pointer" \
 ./configure --prefix=/home/swarkentin/target   \
 --enable-static --disable-shared
```

I am getting an error:

```
checking thread related cflags... -D_REENTRANT
checking for pthread_create/pthread_join... no
checking for pthread_create/pthread_join in -lpthread... no
checking for pthread_create/pthread_join in -lpthread32... no
checking for pthread_create/pthread_join in -lpthreads... no
checking for pthread_create/pthread_join in -lthread... no
checking for pthread_create/pthread_join in -ldce... no
configure: error: I can't find the libraries for the thread implementation
        posix. Please choose another thread implementation or
        provide information on your thread implementation.
        You can also run 'configure --disable-threads'
        to compile without thread support.
```

How can I point/find posix thread libraries to make it past configure step?

Let's say, I include --disable-threads.  Now I can finish configure, but make ends with an error:

```
gcancellable.c: In function 'IA__g_cancellable_reset':
gcancellable.c:372: error: 'g__cancellable_lock' undeclared (first use in this function)
gcancellable.c:372: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
gcancellable.c:372: error: for each function it appears in.)
gcancellable.c: In function 'IA__g_cancellable_disconnect':
gcancellable.c:764: error: 'g__cancellable_lock' undeclared (first use in this function)
make[5]: *** [gcancellable.lo] Error 1
```

Comment: Why are you compiling this? It looks like it is in Debian as libglib2.0-0. The squeeze version is 2.24.2-1. If you want to recompile, use the Debian sources, and recompile those using `debuild` or `debuild binary`. If you want to adjust what you use to compile it with, you can do that in `debian/rules`.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the `libc6-dev` package.

Have you run `apt-get install build-essential` yet?

Comment: I do have that installed, but I want to build from a different glibc and gcc source.  I updated my question with --disable-threads used, and get a different error altogether.

Comment: @SheldonWarkentin If you aren't using the system's standard compiler and libraries, you need to mention that in your question! The problem could be due to a bad installation, or (more likely) to not having pointed the compilation process at the custom compiler and libraries properly. Explain how and where you installed gcc and the C library development files, and how you configured Glib.

Comment: I have updated my question with my configure command.  My glibc is a static library.  I narrowed down where the call fails.  In config.log, on a call 'checking for pthread_create/pthread_join... no', I noticed that it references '/lib64/libpthread.so.0'.  If I were to add --static to the gcc call, this would work with MY glibc.  So... maybe I am just missing a flag that adds the '-static' parameter to gcc calls generate by glibc configure.

Comment: It's called `--static`. If that's what you are wanting to do, then just add it to your CFLAGS and be done with it.

Comment: Almost there I think...  make fails at:: warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
../../gio/.libs/libgio-2.0.a(libinotify_la-inotify-kernel.o)(.text+0x195): In function `_ik_startup':
: undefined reference to `inotify_init'
../../gio/.libs/libgio-2.0.a(libinotify_la-inotify-kernel.o)(.text+0x35b): In function `_ik_watch':
: undefined reference to `inotify_init'
...